# Limit amount of parameters in query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite

I just want to limit the amount of parameters that nginx/apache allows to pass. For example: if someone tries to access a link like `test.php?arg1=value&arg2=value&arg3=value` give them a 404 error or 403 it doesn't matter. If the URL contains more than two arguments/parameters it should be blocked by the webserver. Is there a way to achieve this task ? I've tried something for Apache htaccess but with no success. I'm talking about limiting the amount of parameters for the entire website not just one page/file.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (([a-z]+){3,})=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /404.php? [R=404,L]
```

Can this thing be done for Apache and Nginx ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplistic approach would be to limit the number of `&` characters in the `$args` string.

If there are only two parameters, there is usually only one `&` to join them, so the sequence `&.*&` should not exist.

For example:

```
if ($args ~ "&.*&") { return 403; }
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Nice way to put it. I've did something for htaccess using the same approach. Thanks man !